# Why is print(bid > highest_bid) returning true, when bid = 3 and highest_bid =2000?

Tags: python, django

I'm making a simple form in Django without using the in-built Django forms. To process the form I'm just using HTML/Django template and Python in the views.py file.

I don't understand why `print(bid > highest_bid)` is returning True when:

Highest bid = 2000.6

bid = 3

listing_detail.html

```html
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'listing-detail' object.id %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="hidden" name="highest_bid" value="{{ highest_bid }}">
    <input type="number" step=".01" min="" placeholder="0.00" name="bid">
    <button type="submit">Place bid</button>
</form>
```

views.py

```py
# place bid
        highest_bid = request.POST.get("highest_bid", "") #2000.6
        print(f'Highest = {highest_bid}')
        bid = request.POST.get("bid", "") #3
        print(f'bid = {bid}')
        print(bid > highest_bid) # returns True
        if 'bid' in request.POST and bid > highest_bid:
            #bid = float(request.POST['bid'])
            new_bid = Bids(bid_value=bid, bidder=self.request.user, item=item)
            new_bid.save()
        return redirect(reverse("listing-detail", args=listing_id))
```

This means that the bid is being saved to the database. Even though I am trying to only save the highest bid with the line

```py
if 'bid' in request.POST and bid > highest_bid:
```

Comment: But, when bid = 1, then bid > highest_bid returns False. This is interesting.

Comment: try to put int(bid) and int(highest_bid) and compare to see the results.somthing like this print(int(bid) > int(highest_bid)).or float(...)

Comment: Yes! I've converted both to floats and problem solved. I assumed that they wouldn't be a string because the <input type="number">. Thank you!

Comment: I just notice something.try to make the bid field required because if not this "float(bid) > float(highest_bid)" will throw a ValueError.if the user submits the form without the bid you will get a error from the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are comparing string not number.to avoid this you should cast your variable something like this.

```
print(int(bid) > int(highest_bid)) or print(float(bid) > float(highest_bid))
```

try to change this

```
if 'bid' in request.POST and bid > highest_bid:
```

to

```
if 'bid' in request.POST and float(bid) > float(highest_bid):
```